# Use type guard to narrow down return type of a function?

Tags: typescript

I am wondering if there is a way to use a type guard to narrow the return type of a function based on the parameters. Here's a simple example:

```
// Can this be made into a typeguard that predicts the outcome of `getColor(thing)`?
function isRed(thing: string): boolean {
  // return some magic that checks if the thing is red
}

function getColor(thing: string): 'red' | 'blue' {
  // return some color that identifies the color of the thing
}
```

Lets assume I have another function, that takes only red as a parameter:

```
function paintWithRed(color: 'red'): void { ... }
```

This will give me a type error:

```
function main() {
  if(isRed('tomato')) {
    paintWithRed(getColor('tomato')); // at design time `get('tomato')` could be `'blue'`
  }
}
```

`getColor('tomato')` could be `'blue'`, but because of `isRed('tomato')` I know that it is `'red'`.

Pretty sure this is not possible, but maybe I missed some fancy TypeScript feature?

**Update:**

I am aware that I can find a workaround for this. But I am interested if there is a TypeScript native way to basically connect `isRed()` and `getColor()`. Logically, I imagine this:

```
// tell the compiler that guarding with `isRed()` has an effect on the result of `getColor()`
function isRed(thing: string): getColor(thing) is 'red' {
  // return magic
}
```

**Update:**

As most suggestions here are related to nullish checks, I changed the example above to a union type of literal strings instead. I know the example isn't realistic.

Comment: There is no way for TypeScript to predict something that will happen at runtime. You can't narrow the return type down to `true` or `false`.

Comment: This is not about runtime, though. I know, at design time, that `get('someKey')` is not `undefined` within the if clause in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) `??`:

```
function main() {
  if(hasKey('someKey')) {
    doSomething(get('someKey') ?? '');
  }
}
```

Then, if `get('someKey')` returns `null` or `undefined`, it will return what's behind the `??` (so in this case an empty string).

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue, because `get('someKey')` can still be `undefined`. I am aware that I can find a workaround, but I am really interested in whether this is possible without additional steps.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working example :**

As **function get(key:string)** has return type either string | undefined
so, in 
**function doSomething(value: string | undefined) should accept string | undefined** parameter type.

```js
const cache: Record<string , string> = {};

function hasKey(key: string): boolean {
  return key in cache;
}

function get(key: string): string | undefined {
  return cache[key];
}

function doSomething(value: string | undefined): void {
  console.log(value)
}


function main() {
  if(hasKey('someKey')) {
    doSomething(get('someKey'));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is merely a workaround. Imagine I want to call multiple functions within the if clause, where I pass the result of `get('someKey')`. I would have to check if it is `undefined` in all of them. Although I already know it cannot be `undefined` in the if clause.

Comment: for the `get('somekey')` we know what are the possible return type of it so, according to it we can define the `param type`

Answer (score 0):

It is really a design decision on your end. You have 3 options.

Option 1 is to make `get` function to return value no matter what:

```
function get(key: string): string {
  return cache[key]!;
}
```

This option is dangerous since you may use `get` without `hasKey` and then you may get `undefined` and doSomething is in danger of dealing with unexpected `undefined`.

Option 2 is to make doSomething to accept `string | undefined` as Aniket Raj suggested:

```
function doSomething(value: string | undefined): void {
  console.log(value)
}
```

Option 3 is not to use `hasKey` at all:

```
function main() {
  const val = get('someKey');
  if (val != null) {
    doSomething(val);
  }
}
```

Make your choice and get ready to accept the consequences of it.

Comment: Currently, I am doing something similar to option 3, however this is not the point of the question. I wonder if it is possible to achieve a connection between two functions through a type guards. I guess the answer is "no", though 

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to overcome that common problem is to use the typescript assertion operator `!`.

```
function main() {
  if(hasKey('someKey')) {
    doSomething(get('someKey')!); // no more error
  }
}
```

`!` tells typescript that what comes before it does not include `undefined`.

Comment: Sure, but this is dangerous and would cause issues outside of the if clause.

Comment: It's not dangerous if `hasKey('someKey')===true` implies `get('someKey')!==undefined`.
You know the domain of your problem.  Wasn't your question motivated by the fact that you wanted the compiler to know that `hasKey('someKey')===true` implies `get('someKey')!==undefined`?  If not then I don't understand the point.

Comment: What do you mean by *would cause issues outside of the if clause* ?  The `!` only applies at the exact point where it is place - it doesn't affect anything else.

Comment: I see where the confusion comes from. My point is - I am not looking for workarounds. Using `!` refers to the example I gave. If I change it to 'isA: (val: string) => boolean' instead of `hasKey()` and `get()` to `get: (val: string) => 'a' | 'b'`, then the equivalent of `get('someKey')!` would be `get('someKey') as 'a'`. This isn't much better than `as any` and I can call it anywhere in my code (not just the if clause). There isn't anything special about the code in the if clause except for my knowledge. I am looking for a solution where the if clause is special, like when using a type guard.

Comment: You said - `There isn't anything special about the code in the if clause except for my knowledge. ` Don't underestimate your own knowledge!  Your brain is one the most complex and intelligent devices known to mankind.  Beats ChatGPT hands down!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [tiny-variant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-invariant) if you are ok with installing an npm package.

With tiny-variant, we only need to add 1 line to actually narrow down the type:

```
function main() {
  invariant(hasKey('someKey'), "the key should be there");
  doSomething(get('someKey'));
}
```

As above, `invariant` will check if `hasKey('someKey')` is a truthy value. If not, it will throw an exception. The good thing is, tiny-variant **will** throw an exception so that you can actually know where the problem is and try to fix it.

If you're finding a solution to bypass the trouble on production, other comments are better solutions.